# How to get index of items return by limit & descending createAt

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform

This is the first time I've used Parse, I'm loving it so far, reading and writing data is working.

I now want to do something seemingly simple, but in the context of Parse seems like a pain to implement and my google-fu is failing me.

When I find the items like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(CommentClass);
query.limit(2);
query.descending('createdAt');
query.find({
    success: function(object) {
        callback({
            comments: object
        });
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        console.log('there was an error');
    }
});
```

I want to know what indexes of the returned items are in the total list. If my list has 5 items, this will return the last 2 created, but there's no way - without another request knowing the number of items in the list.

Comment: Ok I'll add some snippets, but where should I go to try and work this out? The docs suggest an approach but don't explain any further.

Comment: What should the index be? Not just the item order in your results?

Comment: Is it "index in the list" or "index (of creation) in the class" ?

Comment: Index in the list, if I have 4 items in the list, when I add a new one I want it's index to be 4/5 depending on if it's 0 based or not

Comment: What is the difference between what you want and the line number that the list itself gives you ?

Comment: If I'm paginating and getting items 100-199, I want each item to have the correct index for the whole list not just the index of the items that have been returned

Comment: The start point and index in lost do give you that

Comment: I reworded the question and hopefully it's a lot more clear what I'm trying to do. I want the last N number of created items and to know what their index is in the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an easy way to do it in Parse. One way is to keep a global index in a separate object. In every new comment you need to get this global index, increment it, and put it into the comment. But it can get messy in case of comment deletions. Here is an example assuming no comment deletion:

**SequenceForComment.js**

```
// A class called SequenceForComment. Only one row. 
// Only one integer property called 'sequence'.
// You can create the row by using the Parse dashboard in the beginning. 

var SequenceForComment = Parse.Object.extend("SequenceForComment");

function getSequenceForComment(callback) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(SequenceForComment);
  return query.first().then(function (object) {
    // https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_increment
    //Increment is atomic.
    object.increment('sequence');
    return object.save();
  }).then(function (object) {
    callback(object.get('sequence'));
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    callback(undefined);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getSequenceForComment: getSequenceForComment
};
```

**main.js**

```
var SequenceModule = require("cloud/SequenceForComment.js");

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Comment", function(request, response) {
  var comment = request.object;

  // First time this comment will be saved.
  // https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_isNew
  if (comment.isNew()) {

    // Get a sequence/index for the new comment
    SequenceModule.getSequenceForComment(function(sequence) {
      if (sequence) {
        comment.set("sequence", sequence);
        response.success();
      } else {
        response.error('Could not get a sequence.');
      }
    });
  } else { // Not a new save, already has an index
    response.success();
  }
});
```